# DSC Extension for linux. Error in the dsc.py

Tags: azure, powershell, configuration, agent, dsc

Could u please help?

During the DSC Installation for Linux I'm receiving the following issues:
[image]

**OS**: Linux (ubuntu 20.04)
I'm using the following script for extension provisioning:

```
$vmname = 'ds'
$location = 'westeurope'
$rgName = 'rg-name'

$extensionName = 'DSCForLinux'
$publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'
$version = '2.71'

# You need to change the content of the $privateConfig and $publicConfig 
# according to different scenarios in section 3
$privateConfig = '{
  "StorageAccountName": "<accountname>",
  "StorageAccountKey": "<id-here>"
}'

$publicConfig = '{
  "ExtensionAction": "Push",
  "FileUri": "C:\\_Projects\\test.mof"
}'

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMName $vmName -Location $location `
  -Name $extensionName -Publisher $publisher -ExtensionType $extensionName `
  -TypeHandlerVersion $version -SettingString $publicConfig -ProtectedSettingString $privateConfig
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please mention the file uri as file present inside the Azure storage>container.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried in our environment and faced the same issue as yours .
As a workaround you can try below:

Alternative solution :-

we can use [***`Publish-AzVMDscConfiguration`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/publish-azvmdscconfiguration?view=azps-7.1.0) cmd to upload DSC script to Azure blob storage.

For e.g:-

```
Publish-AzVMDscConfiguration -ConfigurationPath "C:\Sample.ps1" -AdditionalPath @("C:\ContentDir1", "C:\File.txt") -ConfigurationDataPath "C:\SampleData.psd1"
```

then you can try with [***`Set-AzVMDscExtension`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmdscextension?view=azps-7.1.0#code-try-2) to Configure the DSC extension on a virtual machine .

For e.g:-

```
Set-AzVMDscExtension -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup001" -VMName "VM13" -ArchiveBlobName "Sample.ps1.zip" -ArchiveStorageAccountName "Stg" -ConfigurationName "ConfigName" -ConfigurationArgument "@{arg="val"}" -ArchiveContainerName "WindowsPowerShellDSC" -ConfigurationData "SampleData.psd1" -Version "1.10" -Location "West US"
```